# Mulesoft Dataweave zero zoned timestamp conversion

Tags: datetime, dataweave, mulesoft

I am looking to convert a Datetime field into ZonedDatetime but with Zero timestamp.
I have a function like below -

```
fun dateInSecToDateTimePST(d : String) = if (d != null)
                            (d as Number as DateTime {unit: "seconds"} >> "CST")
                        else null
```

The output of this is

```
2020-11-20T21:30:00-06:00
```

But The output what I am expecting is like below-

```
2020-11-20T00:00:00-06:00
```

Timestamp will always remain zero but with offset. Any suggestion ? I am using `%dw 2.0` and **Mule4**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the date time types you can breakup the datetime input and concat it back together with the zeroed time piece like this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun dateInSecToDateTimePST(d : String) = do { 
    var date = (d as Number as DateTime {unit: "seconds"}) as Date
    var time = "00:00:00" as Time
    var zone = "CST" as TimeZone
    ---
    if (d != null)
        date ++ time ++ zone
    else null
}
---
dateInSecToDateTimePST(payload.time)
```

you could also have the timezone be dynamic as well if needed.